How do I move a pivot column to the collection when exporting JSON in Laravel?
I'm using Laravel 10 (planning to switch to 11 soon) to expose an API. Below is a simplified version of the issue that I'm having.
I have a table with users and a table with groups, and I have a many-to-many relationship between them. The pivot table has a column created_at which basically comes down to the moment that the user joined the group. When a user is retrieved through the API, I'm fetching the related groups with the pivot. This results in a JSON that looks like this (omitting irrelevant parts)
{
  'groups':[
     {
        'name': 'group A',
        'pivot': {
            'created_at': '2024-...'
        }
     },
     ...
  ]
}

However, I would prefer an output that looks like this:
{
  'groups':[
     {
        'name': 'group A',
        'joined': '2024-...'
     },
     ...
  ]
}

What is the best way to achieve this? I could completely handcraft the JSON, but then I'm losing quite a lot. There are other endpoints that expose groups outside of the context of a user, and these should not be affected.

Usually, to modify JSON you can create resource
php artisan make:resource UserResource

In the UserResource
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'groups' => $this->groups->map(function ($group) {
            return [
                'name' => $group->name,
                'joined' => $group->pivot->created_at
            ];
        })
    ];
}

In Controller
public function show($id) # in your method
{
    $user = User::with('groups')->findOrFail($id);
    return new UserResource($user); # call the UserResource
}


You can use laravel getAttribute magic method and appends the name to the query.
You can do like this on your model:
protected $appends = ['joined'];


public function getJoinedAttribute(): string
{
    return $this->pivot->created_at
}

